# Zappa Error unable to find view (jade template)

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, pug, zappa

I am trying a zappa node application and am unable to get it working beyond a trivial example.

I have application.coffee

```
     require('zappajs') ->
       @set views: "#{__dirname}/views"
       @set 'view engine': 'jade'
       @use 'bodyParser', 'methodOverride', @app.router, 'static'


       @configure
         development: => @use errorHandler: {dumpExceptions: on}
         production: => @use 'errorHandler'

       @get '/': -> @render 'index'
```

and i am getting an error. Zappa seems to be prepending a guid to the file name.

```
    example/app/views/7b16eeab-de6f-41b0-b196-8f23f4b7237d/index.jade
```

Here is the complete trace

```
        Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory   '/Users/irfn/project/example/app/views/7b16eeab-de6f-41b0-b196-8f23f4b7237d/index.jade'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:338:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:182:15)
    at Object.rethrow (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/jade/lib/runtime.js:155:27)
    at parse (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:116:13)
    at Object.exports.compile (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:163:9)
    at Function.exports.compile (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/zappajs/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:68:33)
    at ServerResponse.res._render (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/zappajs/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:417:18)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/zappajs/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:318:17)
    at Object.zappa.app.app.(anonymous function).apply.concat.render (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:593:33)
    at Object.zappa.app.app.(anonymous function).apply.concat.ctx.render (/Users/irfn/project/example/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:545:31)
```

Here is how my package json dependencies are setup

```
   "dependencies": {
      "coffee-script": "1.3.3",
      "underscore": ">= 1.3.3",
      "stylus": ">= 0.28.2",
      "zappajs": ">= 0.3.10",
      "jade":   ">= 0.18.0"
    },
     "devDependencies": {
       "watchr": "*",
       "mocha": "*",
       "chai":  "*",
       "request": "*"
     },
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Came across this myself - did not have the time to track down the cause but there is an easy workaround:
instead of

```
@get / : ->
    @render index: {key:value}
```

use the more old school connect-style

```
@app.get '/', (req,res) -> 
    res.render 'index', {key:value}
```

Hope this helps you get over the hump.

PS:
Come to think of it, I assume it might have something to do with the way zappa evaluates coffee(k/c)up templates by default. In this case it might be trying to apply that logic to jade which breaks.